# How to programmatically change user password in Active Directory C/C++

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory

I want to write a small program that uses Domain Administrator credentials to do some operations in Active Directory. One of these operations is to reset the password of domain users.

I looked on the internet and found some answers (many for C #), but I couldn't find anything that talked about using an administrative credential to leave a domino user password in c/c++.

My question is: Is it possible to reset a domain user password using administrative credentials? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: Isn't this an it admin task rather than a programming issue?

Comment: The [Active Directory Service Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi) most likely offer anything you'd ever need. If you insist on avoiding PowerShell.

Comment: [NetUserChangePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword) function changes a user's password for a specified network server or domain. If you are programming for Active Directory, you may be able to call certain Active Directory Service Interface (ADSI) methods to achieve the same result you can achieve by calling the network management user functions. For more information, see [IADsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsuser) and `IADsComputer`.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell maybe?

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$newPass" -Force)
```

Change $user and $newPass.